# Want to get the dataframe of values that are deviations from the mean based on a factor column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

Example:

So lets say I have this data frame.

```
x = data.frame(factor = as.factor(c('a','a','b','b','c','c')),value1 = c(1,3,2,4,5,3), value2 = c(7,9,3,4,9,3))


    factor value1 value2
1      a      1      7
2      a      3      9
3      b      2      3
4      b      4      4
5      c      5      9
6      c      3      3
```

I know how to get the mean per factor, I use this method:

```
aggregate(x[,c(2,3)], list(x$factor), mean, na.rm = T )
```

This give me the following output:

```
  Group.1 value1 value2
1       a      2    8.0
2       b      3    3.5
3       c      4    6.0
```

How do I now go about subtracting from each value in the original dataframe the corresponding mean of its factor. The actual dataset I am using is big so need to have a nice way, I have managed to do it but I used complicated for loops.

So the output that I want would be:

```
  factor value1 value2
1      a     -1   -1.0
2      a      1    1.0
3      b     -1   -0.5
4      b      1    0.5
5      c      1    3.0
6      c     -1   -3.0
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: `with(x, value1 - ave(value1, factor, FUN=mean))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% group_by(factor) %>% mutate(across(c(value1, value2), ~. - mean(.)))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   factor [3]
  factor value1 value2
  <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a          -1   -1  
2 a           1    1  
3 b          -1   -0.5
4 b           1    0.5
5 c           1    3  
6 c          -1   -3
```

Comment: ekoam, so the first '.' refers to the row value and the '.' inside the mean function refers to the group mean?

Comment: `.` refers to the values you are applying that formula to. For example, for group `a` and `value1`, `.` represents `c(1,3)`; for group `b` and `value2`, `.` represents `c(3,4)`.

Comment: ok, so formula " ~. - mean(.) " for group a and value1 translates to := 1 - mean(c(1,3)) when value1 = 1 and 3 - mean(c(1,3)) when value1 = 3 for corresponding values of group a?

Comment: Yes, but since R uses vector calculations, it would be more accurate to say that the formula translates to `c(1,3) - mean(c(1,3))`  for group `a`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this shows that I realy need to get more comfortable with dplyr. Does the sign `~` need to be used because we are applying a function.

Comment: Yes. It is a purrr-style function shorthand, and is equivalent to `function(x) x - mean(x)`. See `?purrr::map` for more information.

Comment: @ekoam also is there a way using the dplyr package to do the equivalent thing that I did to get the mean values. Where I used the `aggregate` function.

Comment: The `dplyr` equivalent is `summarise`. Simply replace `mutate` with `summarise` and `~. - mean(.)` with just `mean`, and you will get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
x = data.frame(factor = as.factor(c('a','a','b','b','c','c')),value1 = c(1,3,2,4,5,3), value2 = c(7,9,3,4,9,3))
#Code
x <- x %>% group_by(factor) %>%
  mutate(Mv1=mean(value1),
         Mv2=mean(value2),
         value1=value1-Mv1,
         value2=value2-Mv2) %>% select(-c(Mv1,Mv2))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   factor [3]
  factor value1 value2
  <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a          -1   -1  
2 a           1    1  
3 b          -1   -0.5
4 b           1    0.5
5 c           1    3  
6 c          -1   -3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `data.table`

```
library("data.table")
setDT(x)
cols <- paste0("value", 1:2)
x[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x - mean(x)), .SDcols=cols, by=factor]
```

or

```
library("data.table")
setDT(x)
x[, sweep(.SD, 2, STATS=colMeans(.SD)), by=factor, .SDcols=2:3]
```